# Prob. 2, Sec. 3.3 in Erwin Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications": How to minimise the norm?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $z$ be a given complex number. Let $M \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be given by 
$$M \colon= \left\{ (\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n ) \in \mathbb{C}^n  \mid  \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i = z \right\}.$$

Then $M$ is convex and complete. Am I right?

What is the vector of minimum norm in $M$ if $\mathbb{C}^n$ is given the

(i)  $\ell^\infty$ norm?

(ii) $\ell^p$ norm, where $1 \leq p < +\infty$?

I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Least knowledgeable about the theory of functions of (several) complex variables, I'm just not sure how to attack this problem!

The more detail, the better.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks. Nice to hear from you.

Comment: You should try this problem for $n=2$ to see how it goes. It'll help you to address the general problem because the behavior won't be too different. Also you don't need any several complex variable theory for this.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in stating that $M$ is both convex and complete.  The proof of this is a fairly straightforward application of the definitions.

The second part doesn't require any particularly high-powered tools for functions of multiple complex variables.

**Hints:**

- $\|x\|_\infty$ is minimized with $\xi_i = \frac{z}{n}$
- Use Hölder's inequality with the vectors

$$
(|\xi_1|,\dots,|\xi_n|), \quad 
\left(\frac{\xi_1}{|\xi_1|}, \dots, \frac{\xi_n}{|\xi_n|} \right)
$$

(if $\xi_i = 0$, take $1$ instead of $\frac{\xi_i}{|\xi_i|} = \frac 00$).

---

**Answer for (ii):**

By using Holder's inequality (as explained in the above hint), we can deduce that for $x = (\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i\right| \leq \|x\|_p \cdot (1^q + \cdots + 1^q)^{1/q}
$$
So that for any $x \in M$, we have
$$
\|x\|_p \geq \frac{|z|}{n^{1/q}} = |z|n^{(1-p)/p}
$$
So, if we can find an $x \in M$ such that the above inequality is an equality, we will have find the $x$ in $M$ that minimizes $\|x\|_p$.  In particular, taking
$$
x = \left(\frac zn,\dots,\frac zn \right)
$$
we can verify that the desired equality is attained.

Comment: please explain in detail; the hints aren't enough.

Comment: I'll put a more thorough answer in if/when I can.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: cal you please elaborate the first hint also? I'm not as smart as you think I might be.

Comment: The trick is just to use Holder's inequality in the same way, but with $p=\infty$

Comment: I'm not aware of the Holder inequality with $p = \infty$. I only know the Holder inequality with $1 < p < +\infty$.